# Invoke rsync with specific defaults for current folder?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have a local folder which I want to synchronize with a remote folder through SSH, and I'd like to do it through `rsync`. I would always call `rsync` with the same arguments, and same source and destination, when I want to sync this specific folder.

Is there a way to create a **folder-specific** configuration file for `rsync`, placed in this local folder, so that when I simply run `rsync` in this folder, it will automatically take the defaults from the configuration file and start synching? Something like how you'd simply call `git status` in a folder, and it reads the repo from there - no further arguments about the path to the repo given.

Comment: If you always use the same exact rsync command in that folder, couldn't you make a one-line shell script file in that folder for this? The only other method I can think of might be to use rsync as a daemon ([here](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync#Rsync_Daemon)), but I'm unfamiliar with that process.

Comment: you can have `.rsync-filter` files (see `man rsync` and search for both `-F` and `FILTER RULES`) but that doesn't allow you to specify options, only exclude and include and other filtering rules.

Comment: @Ryan: a shell script containing rsync would have been my next option - I've already done that before. Just checking if there's a more elegant way.

Comment: @cas: Thanks, didn't know about filter rules. Will be definitely helpful, since I want to synchronize the working folder of a git repository, and a lot of things have to be kept out of the synchronization.

Comment: I think that [meuh's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) answer is the best you could safely do for this. However, if you *really* wanted to just call `rsync`, you *could* alias the `rsync` command so that calling `rsync` actually calls a wrapper function which first checks for a local config file as you describe, and then calls the `rsync` binary. This is pretty similar to what [meuh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) does, except it will affect all calls to `rsync`. While this means you can "simply run rsync", it *may* have unintended side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write your own little shell script for that. For example, "myrsync" in your PATH holding:

```
#!/bin/bash
ok(){
  if [ -t 0 ] &&
     read -p "ok? $* ? " reply && 
     [ "$reply" = y -o "$reply" = ok ] 
  then "$@"
  fi
}

if [ -f .myrsync ]
then ok rsync $(<.myrsync)
else echo "no .myrsync here in $PWD"
fi
```

This has a function `ok` that tests that stdin is a terminal, then prompts you with the rsync command it has found and if you reply "y" it runs it.
The rest of the script tests for a file `.myrsync` and if so runs the function on its contents.

Comment: This is awesome :)